# Rotate UIImage to call methods on iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-animation

I am looking at taking an image and rotating it to call a method.  The image below has a ring inside it.  What I am looking to do is add UIGestures on that image to allow it to freely rotate, while staying locked in position on x and y axis.  Rotating it would cause for different text to appear in the middle.  Kind of like turning a dial to show the different options.  Are there any good tutorials for doing this kind of thing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try the [the tutorial on creating a dial control](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit) over at Ray Wenderlich.

The key to creating the rotation effect is to capture touches on the view and translate motion along the `x` and `y` axis to a rotation (`container` is the view to be rotated; your image view, in this case):

```
- (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    // 1 - Get touch position
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    // 2 - Calculate distance from center
    float dx = touchPoint.x - container.center.x;
    float dy = touchPoint.y - container.center.y;
    // 3 - Calculate arctangent value
    deltaAngle = atan2(dy,dx); 
    // 4 - Save current transform
    startTransform = container.transform;
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    CGPoint pt = [touch locationInView:self];
    float dx = pt.x  - container.center.x;
    float dy = pt.y  - container.center.y;
    float ang = atan2(dy,dx);
    float angleDifference = deltaAngle - ang;
    container.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(startTransform, -angleDifference);
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @KevinPanko Good point. I added the most relevant code from the post